# Docker CE won't start after upgrade to 18.09 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, docker

When I try to upgrade to the latest version of docker-ce, 18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic, docker fails to start up with the error that it can't find the devicemapper plugin.

```
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41-07:00" level=warning msg="Running experimental build"
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.149758139-07:00" level=info msg="User namespaces: ID ranges will be mapped to subuid/subgid ranges of: lxd:lxd"
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.159295190-07:00" level=info msg="systemd-resolved is running, so using resolvconf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf"
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.159453828-07:00" level=info msg="User namespaces: ID ranges will be mapped to subuid/subgid ranges of: lxd:lxd"
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160388092-07:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160423687-07:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160470021-07:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160482788-07:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160560969-07:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160601454-07:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160588007-07:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160697436-07:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160743537-07:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4200db9f0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160691768-07:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42009a1d0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160760682-07:00" level=warning msg="Unable to locate plugin: devicemapper, retrying in 1s"
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160773855-07:00" level=info msg="blockingPicker: the picked transport is not ready, loop back to repick" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160922445-07:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42009a1d0, READY" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:41 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:41.160999752-07:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4200db9f0, READY" module=grpc
Nov 18 22:16:42 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:42.161035546-07:00" level=warning msg="Unable to locate plugin: devicemapper, retrying in 2s"
Nov 18 22:16:44 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:44.161383150-07:00" level=warning msg="Unable to locate plugin: devicemapper, retrying in 4s"
Nov 18 22:16:48 server dockerd[6351]: time="2018-11-18T22:16:48.161695623-07:00" level=warning msg="Unable to locate plugin: devicemapper, retrying in 8s"
```

Everything was working fine before the upgrade.  When I revert back to the previous version of docker-ce, 18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu it works again.  Any ideas would be wonderful.

daemon.json:

```
{
    "userns-remap": "lxd",
    "userland-proxy": false,
    "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
    "storage-opts": [
      "dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/docker-thinpool",
      "dm.use_deferred_removal=true",
      "dm.use_deferred_deletion=true"
    ]
}
```

uname:

```
Linux server 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Thanks for taking your time to look this over.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252818/ubuntu-16-04-latest-update-broke-docker-docker-ce

Comment: I don't think the above answer works for this, I see different issues. However, I think the OP might need to reinstall docker-ce to fire all necessary dependencies-install + trigger ubuntu 18.04 specific triggers.
I have no issues running CE on 18.04, but I fully reinstalled it after the upgrade

Comment: I completely removed the old docker-ce and reinstalled the newer one.  But still can't start it.

Answer (score 2):

The deprecated devicemapper was removed from the Ubuntu docker package [due to the code move to containerd](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/452#issuecomment-440427796).

Until this has been fixed I would recommend to pin the package to the 18.06 version.

```
cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/docker  <<EOF
Package: docker-ce
Pin: version 18.06*
Pin-Priority: 1000
EOF

apt-get remove docker-ce runc docker containerd.io
apt-get install docker-ce thin-provisioning-tools
journalctl -xe | grep docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to start dockerd after removing my storage-opts and storage-driver configuration.

Based on the information at the link from @Ivan, I removed docker-ce and performed an `autoremove`. I then reinstalled docker-ce. A post install trigger attempted to start dockerd which failed, but the install process provided the `journalctl -xe` command to diagnose the problem.

Running `journalctl -xe` displayed an error message which caused me to suspect devicemapper. Removing the configuration allowed dockerd to start normally.